# Get client's IP address using .NET Standard 1.4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-standard

I am writing a .NET Standard library to log users' IP address whenever they are trying to login to the system. I checked with .NET API Browser and I couldn't find  `System.Web` API in .NET Standard 1.X so I can't use `HttpContext` to get IP. Is there anything that I can use in .NET Standard 1.X to get client's IP address?

Thanks.

Comment: `System.Web` available as part of .Net Standard 2.0. You can find available dll support [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0.md)

Comment: @SivaGopal, thanks for the reply. I am aware that `System.Web` is available in 2.0. But I have to support .NET Core 1.0 so I can only write the library in .NET Standard 1.X

Comment: .Net Standard is in rapid evolution phase, if that is a correct phrase I can coin! Also it was clearly said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) **The higher the version, the more APIs are available to you**. So AFAIK one quick approach as you know would be to accept IP as parameter relying on your application.

Comment: @SivaGopal, okay, it also seems that 4.6.1 is supported in .NET Standard 2.0. Thank you, I will give 2.0 a try!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private string GetUserIP()
{
    string ipList = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipList))
    {
        return ipList.Split(',')[0];
    }

    return Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but `Request.ServerVariables` is part of `System.Web` right? I don't think `System.Web` is part of .NET Standard 1.X

Comment: Check this  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525396(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: available since 1.1  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @shiwankachathuranga The .Net framework in question here is [.Net Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard). If you can provide a sample to get IP address in any of .Net Standard 1.x framework, would help OP greatly.